# Associator-Commutator Identity

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm currently working on a hw problem that I've been stuck on for far longer than I should be, and I'm starting to wonder if the problem was written wrong in the first place. I would just like someone to verify whether the identity that I am proving is correct or not so I know if I'm wasting my time or there's just something I'm not seeing.

The identity is as follows:

$a[b,c]-[ab,c]+[a,b]c=[a,c,b]-[a,b,c]-[c,a,b]$

where $[a,b]:=ab-ba$ and $[a,b,c]:=(ab)c-a(bc)$

a,b,c are elements of an arbitrary binary ring.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is clearly written wrong. While the ring might not be commutative, multiplication is certainly associative, which would give that the right hand side is always zero.

Comment: I don' think we can assume that multiplication is associative otherwise it would be an associative binary ring.

Comment: What is your definition of a binary ring?

Comment: (R,+,*) where (R,+) is an abelian group and * distributes over +.

Comment: What textbook is this from? Traditionally, a ring is understood to be associative unless it is specifically stated to be nonassociative.

Comment: https://math.berkeley.edu/~wodzicki/H113.S15/H113-20150305.pdf

Comment: I would cntrl+f to find the section on rings.

Comment: In the context, you are correct. Those notes indicate that a ring does not a priori have associativity. In that case, @David Wheeler has a good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may be written wrong. This is what I get:

$[a,c,b] - [a,b,c] - [c,a,b] = (ac)b - a(cb) - (ab)c + a(bc) - (ca)b + c(ab)$

$= a(bc) - a(cb) + c(ab) - (ab)c + (ac)b - (ca)b$

$= a[b,c] + [c,ab] + [a,c]b = a[b,c] - [ab,c] + [a,c]b$

So I believe the $b$ and $c$ in the third term of the LHS of your identity have been juxtaposed in error.

Comment: That's the exact conclusion I came to, thanks for the confirmation.